# Format values in text cell

Tags: numbers

I have a chart with two percentage columns (min, max), and a third which is supposed to show the min-max range in absolute values. I use the formula `=A2*60&" - "&B2*60` in cell `C2`. The expected result is (for an absolute max of 60):

```
Min      | Max     | Range
33.3%    | 50.0%   | 20 - 30
```

Here's what I get:

```
Min      | Max     | Range
33.3%    | 50.0%   | 2000.0% - 3000.0%
```

The percentage columns are formatted to display a percentage value with one decimal, and this format is somewhat applied to the text.

If I change the formula to `=A2*$C$1&" - "&B2*$C$1`, I get:

```
Min      | Max     | 60
33.3%    | 50.0%   | 20.000 - 30.000
```

For every format on `C1` I get 3 decimals in the expression, except if I set the format to only one decimal in `C1`, I really get one decimal in the expression.

Question: How do I choose how the numbers are displayed in `C2`?

Comment: Can't you play with number formatter on the toolbar at the top? There should be options for data type, number of decimal places etc

Comment: It has absolutely no effect on the cell with the formula.

Comment: Hmmm odd I'll have a look in a bit

Answer (score 1):

Using extra cells (which can be hidden) appears to be the only way I have found to control the *Automatic* formatting that **Numbers** applies.

In separate cells for each desired number, do the calculation.
`A2*60` then in another cell, `B2*60`

In your `Range` column, concatenate the results.  So if the cells containing `20` and `30` are in `E2` and `F2` then `Range` would have this formula:

`E2 & " - " & F2`

or:

`concatenate(E2," - ",F2)`

Then if desired, hide E and F columns.

[image: Formula results]